# Where does the difference in those snippets of iText code come from?

Tags: java, itext

Working with iText, I came upon a difference between two snippets that I can't explain.

Snippet A:

```
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.addElement(new Paragraph("a", SOME_FONT));
    cell.addElement(new Paragraph("b", SOME_FONT));
    cell.addElement(new Paragraph("c", SOME_FONT));
    /*
       outputs: 
               a
               b
               c
    */
```

Snippet B:

```
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("a", SOME_FONT));
    cell.addElement(new Paragraph("b", SOME_FONT));
    cell.addElement(new Paragraph("c", SOME_FONT));
    /*
       outputs: 

               b
               c
    */
```

Where does the difference come from? Both cells are added to PdfPTable afterwards. Thanks for the help.

Regards,
al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet, you are using `PdfPCell` in **composite mode**. In the second snippet, you start in **text mode**, and then you switch to **composite mode** (triggered by using the `addElement()` instead of the `addText()` method). When switching from **text mode** to **composite mode**, all text previously stored in the column is discarded.

Google for **text mode** versus **composite mode** and you'll find more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is one very useful thing to know! :)